# Android custom tite bar showing grey padding

Tags: android, layout, custom-titlebar

I have created a custom title bar in an android app, however the custom title bar is surrounded by grey padding which I can't seem to get rid off.

[image]

Below are the relevant files associated with the title bar.

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**onCreate()**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.custom_main_title);
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**custom_main_title.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#3E1650"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title_contact_name"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="60dp"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:paddingRight="16dp"
         android:paddingLeft="16dp"
         android:text="title"
         android:textColor="#EADE00"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_contact_plus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="#EADE00"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: some images would help

Comment: @ScottS image is attached

Answer (score 0):

Use toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
android:layout_height="50dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/screen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3E1650"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/title_contact_name"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="60dp"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:paddingRight="16dp"
     android:paddingLeft="16dp"
     android:text="title"
     android:textColor="#EADE00"
     android:textSize="18sp"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:typeface="serif" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_contact_plus"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="#EADE00"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

in onCreate();

```
Toolbar actionBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
```